# JMeter: How to handle cookies in multiple threads?

Tags: testing, jmeter, session-cookies

I am having a test plan in jmeter, that contains setUp, tearDown and one main thread.

> setUp thread logins the application (open a session).
>
> main thread executes to perform a task in same session.
>
> tearDown thread logout the application (close the session).

This is not possible because the cookies of setup thread can not be used in other thread so we can not get the session in other threads.

Please tell me how this is possible?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share data (including cookies) between thread groups using [Inter-Thread Communication](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/InterThreadCommunication)

But I can't understand why do you want to do it. I advice to do:

```
Thread Group
  HTTP Sampler (login)
  .
  Put your logic here. Maybe you need Loop Controller or Synchronizing Timer here
  .
  HTTP Sampler (logout)
```

Comment: I have to use it because i want to test load on a specific page that is in my main thread. and other two thread for login and logout application that will run only once

Comment: @abhishekameta I advice you to put it to [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)

Comment: but this will not create load on server because request can't be sent spontaniously. so i have to use different thread

Comment: @abhishekameta I don't understand what do you mean by "request can't be sent spontaniously"

Comment: Loop sends request one by one and I want to send 1000 of request at a same time so I can't use loop.

Comment: I have asked for Synchronizing Timer and all the possible solutions that you have given but he said me strictly to do only that.

Comment: What is "that"? And who is he?

Comment: he is my boss and he said me to handle cookies in multiple threads.